# Every reference in Visual Studio Project is showing as invalid

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have a very strange issue where I have opened a known to be working Visual Studio 2010 project but it no longer builds and every reference is shown as not being valid as shown in the screenshot below.

I have no idea why or what to do.

[image: Screenshot of project references]

I have installed Visual Studio 2013 Express so I'm not sure if this may have screwed up something somewhere, but as a test the project is open in 2010 and I'm seeing this issue.

In the error tab of VS it shows the following error:

> Error 1   This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on
>   this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For
>   more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105.
>   The missing file is
>   ....\ServerAdministrator\packages\System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.94.0\build\net40\System.Data.SQLite.Core.targets.  C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2013\Projects\BoardiesITSolutionsLib\BoardiesITSolutions\BoardiesITSolutions.csproj   131 5   BoardiesITSolutions

The ServerAdministrator program that its mentioning is a totally different project, I've tried removing the references to System.Data.SqliteCore and tried telling NuGet to re-add them but no joy.

The warnings are:

`The Referenced component 'WindowsBase' could not be found`
`` The Referenced component `System.Xml.Linq' could not be found ``

All of the warnings are along the same lines as above for each references shown in the screenshot.

Comment: What does it show for warnings in the Error List panel?

Comment: If you look at the .csproj project file in a text editor (it's really just XML), do the references make sense? Do you have that version of the .NET framework installed?

Comment: I've updated my question with the errors/warnings

Comment: I would try removing one of the references and re-adding it. If it works, look in the project file to compare the correct reference with the erroneous ones.

Comment: @Cameron Could you add your comment as an answer and I can accept it. Modifying the csproj file did the trick, it was for some reason referencing DLL's in an old project directory instead of the local project directory

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As requested, my comment as an answer:

---

If you look at the .csproj project file in a text editor (it's really just XML), do the references make sense?

Do you have that version of the .NET framework installed?

Typically the raw project file will give you a more detailed idea of what's going on than the IDE will.

Comment: As mentioned in the question comment the problem was related to some of the references pointing to an old project directory. Thanks for your help

Comment: I moved my project directory to a "deeper level" and forgot to also move the "packages" directory. I realized it by looking in the project file, as recommended by Cameron. Not sure though why the package restore didn't create the "packages" directory in the new project directory location.